# Why am I getting this error as I try from withing the anonymous class?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

I get an error that says :

`no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(<anonymous Runnable>,String,String,int)` as I try to use the `JOptionPane.show...` method. Why is that ?

```
private void connectivityChecker() {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }catch(Exception exc) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted !");
            }

            boolean isConnected = Internet.isConnected();
            if(!isConnected) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have lost connectivity to the server", "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r,"Connectivity Checker - UserGUI").start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are referring to `this`  it points to inner class, not the outer class which you are thinking.

Try to tell that point to `outer class`, not the `anonymous inner class`.

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(OuterClassName.this, <--------
              "You have lost connectivity to the server", 
                  "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you refer `this` within the anonymous class, it refers to the **anonymous class instance** itself. Since you are creating a `Runnable` anonymous instance, this refers to that `Runnable` instance.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(..)` does't accept `Runnable`, so you might want to do something like this

```
private void connectivityChecker() {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }catch(Exception exc) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted !");
            }

            boolean isConnected = Internet.isConnected();
            if(!isConnected) {
                showErrorMessage("You have lost connectivity to the server", "Connection Error" );
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r,"Connectivity Checker - UserGUI").start();
}

private void showErrorMessage(String message, String header) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message, header, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

In above, since `this` is called from `showMessage()`, it refers to the instance of the main class in which `showMessage()` is defined

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet did not even compile for me and throwing an error on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this ...

Because this should be extending Component. Anyways I tried extended my outer class with Component and the code below worked for me without any issues.

```
    if (!isConnected) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ThisAmbiguity.this, "You have lost connectivity to the server", "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

ThisAmbiguity is my outer class. So, when you are referring to this in anonymous inner class so its pointing inner class.